# Get the count of students who have passed all of their subjects

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the amount of students who have passed ALL their subjects (mark >= 4).

Ex:

> Student 1(**OK**):
>
> - Math: 5
> - Chemistry: 4
>
> Student 2(**OK**):
>
> - Philosophy: 7
>
> Student 3(**NOT OK**):
>
> - Math: 3
> - Philosophy: 6
>
> Student 4(**NOT OK**):
>
> - Math: *null*
> - Philosophy: 8

DB:

-students(id)

-subjects_students(id_subject, id_student, mark)

SQL (using MySQL):

```
SELECT count(ss.id_student)
FROM subjects_students ss
WHERE (SELECT count(ss.id_student) 
       FROM students st
       WHERE ss.id_student = st.id)
       =
      (SELECT count(ss.id_student)
       FROM students st
       WHERE ss.id_student = st.id
       AND ss.mark >= 4)
```

I can´t seem to get the right amount. I get students who have passed some subjects, but not all of them.

*EDIT*: mark can be *null*. Do not count these.

**ANSWER**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(ss.id_student) 
FROM subjects_students ss
GROUP BY ss.id_student
HAVING MIN(ss.mark) >= 4 AND COUNT(ss.mark) = COUNT(*)
) src;
```

Comment: It might be easier to find those students who failed at least one subject, then remove them from the list of students.

Comment: Do you want to count students without any entry in subjects_students, too, because they haven't failed any subject yet?

Comment: No, just students who have passed all their subjects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want students who have passed *all* their subjects, then you want to filter out the ones whose mark is too low.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT ss.id_student
FROM subjects_students ss
GROUP BY ss.id_student
HAVING MIN(ss.mark) >= 4;
```

You can then count the students using this as a subquery.

Note that the join to the `students` table is unnecessary.  All the information you need is in `subjects_students`.

Comment: Forgot to tell that mark can be null. How do I avoid it?

Comment: So null means "I have no idea"?  Gordon's method will still work unless you want to eliminate anyone that has no mark in a given class, in which case you would have "MIN(COALESCE(ss.mark, 0)) >= 4.

Comment: Another way to go about this is to find the sum, the count of values and divide the sum by the count and compare it to whatever "passed" is.

Comment: @Leo . . . And what is supposed to happen with a `NULL` mark?

Comment: null means not scored yet. So it's an unapproved subject.
A student with a subject with mark null should not be counted.

Comment: @Leo . . . This query *ignores* marks that are `NULL`.  If you require that all marks be non-NULL then use `and count(mark) = count(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should join the students and subject table, then remove any students who have a subject with a failing grade.

```
SELECT
    a.`id`,
    c.`id_subject`,
    c.`mark`
FROM `students` a
LEFT JOIN `subjects_students` c
ON a.`id` = b.`id_student`
LEFT JOIN `subjects_students` b
ON a.`id` = b.`id_student` AND b.`mark` < 4
WHERE b.`id` IS NULL
GROUP BY a.`id`,c.`id_subject`,c.`mark`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do like Gordon's method here is another that might be slightly slower but can get you to the count of students in the same query without 2 steps.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ss.id_student) as CountOfStudents
FROM
    subjects_students ss
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM subjects_students ss2 WHERE ss.id_student = ss2.id_student AND ss2.mark < 4)
```